# Use REST API to like or rate a SharePoint List Item

Tags: development, rest, api, like

i would like to rate items via rest API.
and i would like get user specific ratings.
so if the user rated an item with 5 stars i want to see 5 stars somewhere in XML from rest API.
By default i receive a XML including RatingCount and AverageRating. (if there is at least one Rating)
But how to get my own rating to display in a UI
And how to rate if there is no Value to change?
I searched for hours, but can t find any real hint. is there even a way to do this via rest?
I am using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Here is JSOM solution for your reference(get rated users and the score):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomJS, 'sp.js');
    function CustomJS() {
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Documents");
        var item = list.getItemById(1);
        ctx.load(item);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
            var _RatedBy = item.get_item('RatedBy');
            var _Ratings=item.get_item('Ratings')
        })        
    }
   </script>
```

For rating, you cold check the similar thread below.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3aec1b3d-3bef-4e9d-b6d6-70ecc6375aaf/set-rating-of-a-host-web-list-column-using-sharepoint-hosted-app?forum=appsforsharepoint